# Strutsの実行時エラー

Tags: java, tomcat, struts

Strutsの実行時エラーについて質問です。

現在StrutsでWebアプリケーションを製作中なのですが、
実行するとブラウザに以下のエラーが表示されます。

type 例外レポート

メッセージ javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: クラス java.XxxForm のbeanを生成する際の例外: XxxForm

説明 The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

struts-config.xmlに記述の誤りがあるのかと思い、
確認しましたが特に問題ないようです。

また、下記の内容も確認しました。
・JSPファイルのhtml:formタグのaction属性の値
・アクションフォーム、アクションクラスの内容

解決方法がなかったため、こちらで質問させていただきました。
詳しい方がいらっしゃいましたらよろしくお願いします。

実行環境

eclipse
Tomcat 7.0
Struts 1.3.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XxxForm`を設定している部分のパッケージ名が違っていませんか？

> クラス java.XxxForm のbeanを生成する際の例外

`XxxForm`は`java`というパッケージにあるんですか?

そのエラーメッセージを出力しているStrutsのコードは以下のようになっています。

```
try {
Class clazz = Class.forName(type);
bean = clazz.newInstance();
        if (bean instanceof ActionForm)
            ((ActionForm) bean).setServlet(servlet);
} catch (Exception e) {
throw new JspException
    (messages.getMessage("formTag.create", type,
             e.toString()));
}
```

つまりクラスのインスタンス化に失敗しているので、`java.XxxForm`というクラスが無いか、正しい引数のコンストラクタが無い等の原因が考えられます。

Comment: Kohei TAMURA さん　回答ありがとうございます。　>XxxFormを設定している部分のパッケージ名が違っていませんか？　　struts-blank-1.3.10.war　を展開して WEB-INF/src/java にソースを格納していましたが、javaフォルダをstrutsフォルダに変更し、そこにソースを格納することでエラーを回避できました。　何故javaフォルダだとエラーになるのか分かりませんが一応解決したので良かったです。　ご指摘ありがとうございました。

Comment: `java`で始まるパッケージはJavaに標準的に含まれるパッケージなので、自作したクラスを格納することはありません。一般的にWebアプリケーションでは、`WEB-INF/classes/`の下に`jp/co/mycompany/myapp/`のようなディレクトリを作成し、その中に`XxxForm.class`が保存されるような構成にします。